# EntityFramework.BulkInsert issues inserting into database

Tags: entity-framework, bulkinsert, sqlbulkcopy

I am attempting to use the [EntityFramework.BulkInsert](https://efbulkinsert.codeplex.com/) library for taking advantage of EF6 and SqlBulkCopy.

The documentation seems very straight forward, however, I cannot get any data populated into the database.

For a complex example, here is the code:

```
public void WriteChunkNoAsync(int chunkCount, bool forceSave = false)
{
    Chunking.Entities.Add(this);
    if (forceSave || Chunking.Entities.Count % chunkCount == 0)
    {
        using (var db = new FlatESContainer())
        {
            //db.Entity.AddRange(Chunking.Entities); //This will work
            db.BulkInsert(Chunking.Entities);
            Chunking.Entities = new List<Entity>();
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

This code will basically insert into a global list until the list count is divisible by chunckCount.

The AddRange function works just fine. So, we decided to create a very simple database with a single table called "Test" and here is the issue we ran into:

```
List<Test> tests = new List<Test>();
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    tests.Add(new Test());
}

using (var context = new SimpleContainer())
{
    //This works fine
    context.Tests.AddRange(tests);
    //This causes an exception: Type 'TestSimpleDatabase.Test' is not found in context 'TestSimpleDatabase.SimpleContainer'
    context.BulkInsert(tests);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

I believe these are separate issues but maybe someone in the stackoverflow community has any idea on why we are having this issue.

Comment: I have the same problem

Answer (score 1):

So, after awhile of attempting to solve the problem, the solution was fairly straight forward. The same rules apply for the SqlBulkCopy where each table has to be inserted, not just the table that has references to other tables (via foreign keys). Very fast though!

Comment: can you please  explain you solution ?

Comment: This means that in EF you can assign an object that represents a table.  The problem was that for the bulk insert to work, you have to actually save  changes to tables you referencing before doing any type of bulk insert.

Comment: Sorry but I don't quite understand your answer here. I have a main table called `Contacts` and its Id column is a foreign key in another table called `ContactExtras`. How can I let my BulkInsert know that we are dealing with foreign keys? I have posted my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32225183/entity-framework-bulk-insert-throws-keynotfoundexception-the-given-key-was-not Would be greateful if you could take a look.

Comment: @Pedram The issue I ran into was that the new entry with the Id was not saved yet. So, EF had no idea how to connect them without first saving that new entry.  So, in your case, it you are bulk inserting into the ContactExtras table, you need to have to first save the changes on the Contact Table before assigning it to the ContractExtras.  So Contact bob = new Contact(); /*Do Stuff with the new Contact */  db.SaveChanges();  //Now you can reference that object in the bulk insert.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to solve this issue by creating a Code First EF6 project. This is a solution but model first would be nice to have.